# Way to get all names of Tables used in MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to get all used MySQL tables' names from a query string?

Comment: All *tables* for the returned columns or all *tables* referenced in the query? There's a difference.

Comment: I have on mind find all tables **from query string** (php)

Comment: So if you have `select ... from X,Y,Z`, you'd want to return `"X", "Y", "Z"`?

Comment: @MarcB Yes but I need to get tables on more complicated queries too, like select from [...] join [...] on [...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `explain` can give you a result set with tables listed, however you cannot use table aliases (it returns the alias) and I've not tested it with all types of queries, so I don't know if it is 100% reliable.

```
explain select * from table1 
inner join table2 on table2.fk_id = table1.pk_id;
```

edit: I should say, "100% reliable *for your purpose*."

Answer (score 2):

use this mysql syntax

```
SHOW [FULL] TABLES [{FROM | IN} db_name]
    [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

for example:

```
SHOW TABLES from _TABLE_NAME_
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the used tables in a query string by prefixing the query with explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ..... FROM ... JOIN .....
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [mysql_field_table()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-table.php), which complements [mysql_field_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-name.php)

They're positional functions, so if you want the table of the 3rd field in the result set, you'd want

```
$select = "SELECT A.x, B.y, C.z FROM A,B,C ...";

$table = mysql_field_table($result, 2); // 0-based positions, returns C
```

Comment: It's OK but it's returns tables only after execute query